# Using iCloud to migrate to a new Mac, and discrepancies in storage totals

Tags: icloud, data-synchronization, storage, migration

I currently have three Macs:

- 2019 5K iMac
- Early 2013 Retina MacBook Pro
- Early 2015 12" MacBook (The tiny one)

In preparation for selling the old laptops to get a new MacBook Pro, I've been updating operating systems and backing up files and cleaning up the laptops. As part of this, I've set the laptops to sync my documents, my desktop, and my photos to iCloud.

All three Macs are on Catalina, and set to automatically keep themselves up-to-date.

The 5K iMac is my new home base machine, and will have the canonical local copies of all my documents and photos.

1. I don't understand why, in System Information > Storage Management, the reported contents of Documents and iCloud Drive are different on all three Macs. If iCloud is meant to store and sync files between all my Macs, wouldn't iCloud look the same to all three Macs, or is this reporting the local storage being taken up by iCloud?
2. Why are the Documents storage and the iCloud storage different, if iCloud *contains* the Documents directory?
3. Am I just confused as to what Documents is in relation to iCloud Drive?

Thank you for any insight. I find this really vexing. I was hoping iCloud would be a help in migration to a new MBP, but perhaps not? I've seen other migration solutions which involve copying home folders, or using rsync, or using Time Machine, and I *could* use any of those, but if iCloud can be an automagic solution, then why not try it?